# Apollo-client run both useLazyQuery and useQuery conditionally - what's the best approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

In my navigation, I have the following "foods" and "cakes" menu items.

Foods page is a list of all foods `url: /foods`

when the user clicked on cakes user redirect to `/foods?food=cakes` meaning the same page of foods above

I used both useQuery and useLazyQuery for these requirements but I'm not 100% proud of my approach I used too much conditional it caused me a  bug my pagination not working as expected.

here's my code.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useQuery, useLazyQuerya } from '@apollo/client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const FoodCategory = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { query } = router
  const variables = { ... }
  const variablesQueryParams = { ... }
  const [isQueryIsTrue, setIsQueryIsTrue] = useState(false)

  // useLazyQuery fetch all cakes only
  const [
    getUrlParams,
    { loading: paramsQueryLoader, data: paramsQueryData },
  ] = useLazyQuery(GET_FOODS, {
    variables: variablesQueryParams,
  })

  // useQuery fetch all foods
  const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_FOODS, {
    variables,
    skip: isQueryIsTrue,
  })


 // checking if url has query parameters
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!Object.keys(query).length > 0) {   
      setIsQueryIsTrue(true)
      getUrlParams()
    }
  }, [getUrlParams, query])

  if (
    isQueryIsTrue
      ? paramsQueryLoader || !paramsQueryData
      : loading || !data
  )
    return <p>Loading...</p>

  const { endCursor, hasNextPage } = isQueryIsTrue
    ? paramsQueryData.foods.pageInfo
    : data.foods.pageInfo

  const nodes = isQueryIsTrue
    ? paramsQueryData.foods.edges.map((edge) => edge.node)
    : data.foods.edges.map((edge) => edge.node)

  const loadMore = async () => {
    if (!hasNextPage) return

    const variables = { ... }

    await fetchMore({
      variables: variables,
    })

  }

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(nodes, null, 2)}</pre>
      <button onClick={loadMore} disabled={!hasNextPage} >
        {hasNextPage ? 'more foods' : 'empty foods'}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FoodCategory
```

Comment: you don't need state or effect for url params, you can use condition directly on skip

Comment: Can expand your comments please perhaps show me your code?

Comment: conditon from effect used in skip

Comment: I see that's clear now.

Comment: One more thing uselazyquery and usequery uses the following loading, data, fetchmore, error etc they're the same correct?

Comment: you can use `useQuery` in both cases

Comment: Hmm,  I do have the kinds of query one is all foods the other one is all cakes only.

Comment: don't explain - think ... skip

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this already instead making conditional checking on useEffect I put my logic on `useQuery` variable like this variables `{ ...,  ...(Object.keys(query).length > 0 && { tags: query.cakes })}` no need useLazyQuery and skip option.

If query parameters is true then filter cakes otherwise default to all foods.